# How can I keep data of a grid after server call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I have a MVC5 page with telerik grids. One grid say A is loaded already. Page has one link on click of which grid B loads using jquery loads. Now on click of one more link grid A should be loaded but i don't want to give server call this time. How can I achieve this?

When Grid B loads data of grid A is not maintained.. How can I maintain data of Grid A?

Comment: hide/show...done!  Where's your code?

Comment: When Grid B loads data of grid A is not maintained.. How can I maintain data of Grid A.

Comment: don't over write it, hide it instead